# Documentation says CakePHP does not support composite keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

In the "conventions page" it says (caution noob here):

"CakePHP does not support composite primary keys. If you want to directly manipulate your join table data, use direct query calls or add a primary key to act on it as a normal model. "

I am very confused by this statement. Composite keys are very basic and form many database structures with identifying relationships.

I am developing my schema and am trying to get around using composites, but it is impossible.

How does this work exactly?

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP expects you to have [set up a database](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html#creating-the-blog-database). You must use certain naming conventions. You then describe it to your CakePHP code via a [configuration file](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#database-configuration).

The database should have its primary keys, alternate candidate keys, foreign keys and constraints as appropriate. But the quoted line is telling you to make sure that every table has a one-column primary key. So this means that where you wouldn't already have such a primary key you add a column, make it the primary key, and declare what were the primary key columns as UNIQUE NON NULL (which is what PRIMARY KEY does), ie as an alternate candidate key.

You should also add any appropriate new versions of constraints including new foreign keys. Note that the old foreign keys can just stay as they were since an SQL FOREIGN KEY declaration only needs to reference a unique field, not a primary key per se. (Ie it's really a foreign superkey declaration.) You should also constrain such new+old foreign key pairs in a table to actually be be a valid pair of values in the referenced table, ie declare the combined columns to be a foreign key to the combined columns as unique. (Ie you don't just want both primary & alternate key values to be in the referenced table, you want them to be there together.)

Comment: While interesting this responder did not really answer my question.   Is there a way to use a composite key in CakePHP?  I am unable to create a single column key for several tables due to the database design.   Please advise

Comment: This reasonably answers the (very general) question you asked. Maybe you would like to ask a *different* question or details about *part* of that question. If you want a more detailed answer then write a more detailed question. Edit your question or ask another one. Even if you cannot change your schema, *your own quote* here says you can use php via "direct query calls". If you don't understand *that*, RTFM and pose a clear question with exactly what you have tried.